# Why doesn't var() cast integer inputs to double instead of throwing an error message?

Tags: matlab

`var()`, which returns the variance of the values in the input, doesn't accept `int32` as argument:

```
data = [0,2,9,2,5,8,7,3,1,9,4,3,5,8,10,0,1,2,9,5,10];

>> var(double(data))
ans =
   11.8905

>> var(int32(data))
Error using var (line 59)
First argument must be single or double.
```

If I remove the type check in the code of `var`, I get:

```
>> var(int32(data))
ans =
   11.9000
```

This is due to the fact that in MATLAB, the result of a subtraction between an integer and a float is an integer, thereby losing precision (e.g. `int32(2) - 2.1 == 0`, instead of -0.1).

So why doesn't `var()` cast integer inputs to double instead of throwing an error message?

`scatterhist()` and `feedforwardnet()` are two other examples of functions that don't accept `int32` as inputs. Among other things, this is annoying for programming languages interoperability, as integers in some other languages might get converted to int32 in MATLAB. Also, semantically, having `int32` as inputs makes sense, sometimes even more than having `double` (e.g. in the case of `feedforwardnet()` where the input specify the number of hidden neurons, where we expect to have a natural number).

Comment: I feel your pain, but are you sure that this is a real question and not just frustration? :-) It sounds like this is the perfect opportunity to put in a [feature request](http://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/contact_support.do) wit The MathWorks. You might also mention that they should actually use `if ~isfloat(x)` if they really want only singles and doubles. As is, the function happily accepts logicals, chars, function handles, cells, structs, etc. (errors are eventually thrown on the latter three). Sigh.

Comment: Thanks! I was curious to know if I had overlooked something, hence the post here :) But if I don't see any answer I'll indeed push a feature request!

Comment: In the second block of code, did you mean `var(int32(data))`?

Comment: Whoops yes, sorry, thanks!

Comment: I think you should accept an answer on this.

Answer (score 2):

I think functions that involve, e.g. division, do not accept `int`s to raise **awareness** of the data types you work with and the potential implicit rounding that might occur in subsequent operations.

Suppose you are using `int32` to save on RAM, you need to explicitly cast your data into `double` to use `var()` since it involves a **division**:

```
data = int32([0,2,9,2,5,8,7,3,1,9,4,3,5,8,10,0,1,2,9,5,10]);
data - var(data)
```

The error will remind you of the datatype and of the potential implicit rounding that will occur between a double variance and your data.

Comment: This could indeed be useful for `var`, which I had taken as the main example my question since it is the most straightforward function I have found having this issue, but it doesn't explain for `scatterhist()` and `feedforwardnet()`. Also, the user will have anyway to be aware of the types when manipulating integers since it is likely that most of the other variables are double, so I don't really see the point in enforcing such a constraint in `var()`.

Comment: I agree on `scatterhist()`, can't think of a reason why it shouldn't accept `int`s, since its scope is graphics. However, unsure about `feedforwardnet()`, since I do not have NNT.